# How to create a dropdown in Twig using the syntax in the manual?

Tags: craftcms

I'm trying to follow the syntax in the docs: https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/blob/v2/README.md to output a `select`. I tried all sorts of syntax but I couldn't get it right…

From the docs, I would have thought this would work, but it just adds the options as an attribute of the select field in the HTML.

```php
{{
  tag(
    'select',
    {
      id: 'type',
      name: 'message[type]',
      options: [
        {
          label: 'option1',
          value: 'option1'
        }
      ],
      class: message and message.hasErrors('message.type')
        ? 'error'
    }
  )
}}
```

The HTML output I get from that:

```html
<select id="type" class="" name="message[type]" options="[{...;}]"></select>
```

I know I could just code it up as "html" but I'd like the keep the markup consistent and it makes the validation cleaner. Any pointer in the right direction much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What I think you want.

I understand that you want to produce a dropdown selection using the `tag()` function, and you want to avoid just slapping in some HTML and calling it a day.

### The HTML we want out of this...

A `<select>` tags options should be inside the element, as `<option>`s.
So the output we want is.

```html
<select id="type" class="" name="message[type]">
   <option value="option1">Option1</option>
   <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

## `tag()` function vs the `{% tag %}` tag

We have two options for making a tag in Craft-Twig. The `tag()` function and the `{% tag %}` tag.

While they give use two routes to the same end...

- `tag()` is better for when the tag has no innerHTML/innerText, or the contents are pulled from another function or API.
- `{% tag %}` is better for when the tag has longer content, or that content is being dynamically generated.

I think `{% tag %}` is the better option for this situation, but I'll go  through them both.

### The `tag()` function

Documentation: [Craft CMS - Functions - tag()](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#tag)

`tag('tag_type',{options_object})`
The tag_type is the <tag_type>. Everything else is optional.

The options_block may include two options that affect the inner contents of a tag:

- `text: "Woo!"`: Text will be HTML encoded and rendered inside your tag.
- `html: "<i>Yay!</i>"`: HTML to be slapped into your tag, with no safety-net.

Everything else is stringified and added as an attribute.
So `id: "thinger` becomes `<tag id="thinger">`

#### Why is your code doing this?

`option={...}` isn't one of `tag()`'s two 'inner stuff' options, so it's just turned into a string and slapped in as an attribute.

#### To get what you want with `tag()`

Just add your desired innerHtml as a string to the options_object's `html` key.

```html
{{
  tag(
    'select',
    {
      html:"<option value="Option1">Option1</option><option value="Option2">Option2</option>"
    }
  )
}}
```

As you can see, though, that can be a bit cumbersome when you have long HTML to insert.

### The `{% tag %}` tag

Documentation [Craft CMS - tags -tag](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/tags.html#tag)

`{% tag %}` works almost exactly like `tag()`, except it let's us put the 's contents inside `{% tag %}` and `{% endtag %}`.

It accepts one argument, the tag type ('element' below), and an optional object via `with`, with each key/value pair becoming attributes on the tag to create.

```html
{% tag 'element' with {
   class: "some class"
   custom_attribute: "some value"
 }
%}
   Your html {{ 'and_Twig()'|upper }} here.
{% endtag %}
```

becomes

```html
<element class="some class" custom_attribute="some value">Your html AND TWIG here.</element>
```

This is better suited for when you have verbose tag contents, or contents that are dynamically generated by other tags/functions.

#### To get what you want with `{% tag %}`

Just put your option tags inside the `{% tag %}...{% endtag %}`

```html
{% tag 'select' with {
   id: 'type',
   name: 'message[type]',
 -%}
   <option value="option1">Option1</option>
   <option value="option2">Option2</option>
{%- endtag %}
```

#### But I don't want to HTML it up...

No problem!

```
{% tag 'select' with {
   id: 'type',
   name: 'message[type]',
 -%}
   {% tag('option', {
      text: "Option1"
      value: "option1"
   }) %}
   {% tag('option', {
      text: "Option2"
      value: "option2"
   }) %}
{%- endtag %}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the very thorough answer! The actual syntax is slightly different, you might wanna update your answer:
```{% tag 'select' with {
    id: 'type',
    name: 'message[type]'
  }
-%}
<option value="option1">
  Option1
</option>
<option value="option2">
  Option2
</option>
{%- endtag %}```

Notice the extra minus sign in `-%}` and `{%- endtag %}`

Comment: Your welcome, and good catch on the tags, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do

```
{% set tags = tag('option', {
   value: '',
   text: 'Select an option'|t
}) %}

{% set opts = [
    'Option 1',
    'Option 2',
    'Option 3'
] %}

{% for opt in opts %}
    {% set tags = tags ~ tag('option', {
        value: opt,
        text: opt
    }) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ tag('select', {
    name: 'iAm',
    class: 'form-control',
    title: 'I Am',
    'aria-label': 'Select an option'|t,
    required: true,
    tabindex: 0,
    html: tags
}) }}
```

You can also

```
{% set opts = {
    '1', 'Option 1',
    '2', 'Option 2',
    '3', 'Option 3',
} %}

{% for val, lbl in opts %}
    {% set tags = tags ~ tag('option', {
        value: val,
        text: lbl
    }) %}
{% endfor %}
```